# Check if all database entries are linked in pairs

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a database table of Accounts.

Each account has (amongst other fields) an `Id` and a `LinkedId`.

The `LinkedId` is used to store the `Id` of another account to which it is linked.

I want to occasionally check the Accounts table to pick out invalidly linked accounts.

An account is invalid if:

1. its `LinkedId` is zero;
2. its `LinkedId` equals its own `Id` (i.e. it's linked with itself);
3. its `LinkedId` is not the `Id` of an account in the Accounts table;
4. its `LinkedId` is the `Id` of an account, but that account's `LinkedId` is not the `Id` of the first account (so if #3 links with #564, then #564 should link with #3).

How do I go about doing this without dragging in all the accounts from the database?

I am using C#, ASP.NET MVC and Entity frameworks.

This is where I got to:

```
List<Account> Accounts = db.Accounts
    .Where(x => x.LinkedId == 0 || x.LinkedId == x.Id || ????????)
    .ToList()
```

Comment: What have you got so far? We can help you refine your code or find/detect bugs, but most won't write it for you.

Comment: I was not asking for someone to write it. I wanted to know which technique is best? My only thoughts are to use a LEFT JOIN with itself and then filter the results.

Comment: @CapIsland: LEFT JOIN is SQL. Did you plan to do this with SQL, or with LINQ to Entities?

Comment: List<Account> Accounts = db.Accounts.Where(x => x.LinkedId == 0 || x.LinkedId == x.Id || ????????).ToList()

I got that far.

Comment: @CapIsland: Excellent. That information should go into your question as code so people have a good starting point to work from.

Comment: I spent ages making that question as clear as possible so as not to waste people's time and hopefully gain some more reputation and instead I get four reputation taken off. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @CapIsland: For the record, I didn't down-vote your answer in the first place. Craig and I were pointing out that you are more likely to get good answers if you post code. For example, if this question had started with that code sample, I likely would have started with that and not wasted both of our time first providing an answer that uses `let`. Now you know for the future that it's typically a good idea to include a small code snippet when possible. Oh, and now that you added code to the question, I've +1'd your question, which should more than counteract the -1 votes you received.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the change in reputation. Thanks. I didn't accuse anyone specifically. And the 'let' reply was not a waste of time. I learned a lot from it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple LINQ statement:

```
var accountsWithInvalidLinks = 
    from a in db.Accounts
    let linkedAccount = db.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(a2 => a2.Id == a.LinkedId)
    where a.LinkedId == 0 ||
        a.LinkedId == a.Id ||
        linkedAccount == null || 
        linkedAccount.LinkedId != a.Id
    select a;
```

Here's an alternative if you're not a fan of query expression syntax. To avoid repetition, I've combined the 3rd and 4th requirements together, which will probably make for a slightly more efficient query:

```
var accountsWithInvalidLinks = 
    db.Accounts.Where(a => 
        a.LinkedId == 0 ||
        a.LinkedId == a.Id ||
        !db.Accounts.Any(a2 => a2.Id == a.LinkedId && a2.LinkedId == a.Id));
```

Comment: Can you do that with LINQ chaining and not use the `let`?

Comment: And I assume the above is translated into an SQL query?

Comment: @CapIsland: Yes, anything in query syntax can be represented as lambda syntax, but it won't always be pretty.

Comment: I just searched StackExchange. You have to change the Let to a Select with a new{} and then perform the Where. I prefer that.n Thanks for your time.

Comment: @CapIsland: Yes, that would be a direct translation of the `let`, but I've posted a cleaner version that you may prefer. Check my update.

Comment: Fantastic. That's not something I would have come up with. Thanks. And is the above translated into a single SQL query on the database?

Comment: @CapIsland: Yes. You can call `accountsWithInvalidLinks.ToString()` to see what the query would look like, and as soon as the `accountsWithInvalidLinks` is evaluated (via `.ToList()`, e.g.), Entity Framework will issue that command to the database to bring back just the items that match these criteria.

Comment: I did not know you could do that either. I've been wondering that for ages. Thank you very much. You made my day. :)